# Right align currency in string format

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting

I'm trying to align some currency to the right:

```
double number1 = 150.45;
double number2 = 1400.95;

//Output  kr. 150,45
Console.WriteLine("{0:c2}", number1);

//Output  kr. 1.400,95
Console.WriteLine("{0:c2}", number2);
```

But I want my output to look like this.

```
//Output kr.   150.45

//Output kr. 1.400,95
```

Where the number is aligned to the right?

Comment: Thanks for the info, in my real project I'am using decimals. Just some quick code I created for this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 string sym = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol;
 Console.WriteLine("{0}{1,10:#,##0.00}",sym, number1);
 Console.WriteLine("{0}{1,10:#,##0.00}",sym, number2);
```

[ideone output](http://ideone.com/1QWF5)

Comment: What if the culture puts the currency symbol after the number?

Comment: @dtb you can look at [`NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyPositivePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern.aspx) and reformat it I guess.

Comment: What if the culture formats currency values not with two decimal places or separates thousands not in groups of 3?

Comment: This globalization stuff is so difficult to get right... maybe one could try to insert spaces between currency symbol and digits after formatting the value as currency.

Comment: @dtb `{0:c2}` in OPs snippet corresponds to two decimal places and that's what I have in my snippet. If it's not two decimal places, the format string has to be changed accordingly. Again, NumberFormatInfo has all the info for current culture; in this case it would be [`NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyDecimalDigits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencydecimaldigits.aspx)

Comment: At the moment, I'm going for this answers. The system is only working with one currency.

Answer (score 7):

it's rather hard for the system to say how many places your numbers have. So you have to decide this yourself. If you have decided you can use something like [String.PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx)

For example

```
Console.WriteLine("kr. {0}", number1.ToString("#,##0.00").PadLeft(10,' '));
```

Comment: Your first suggestion is missing the thousandsseparator, and your second suggestion is not working. See http://ideone.com/NQuHs

Answer (score 2):

This should work for any culture:

```
int width = 20;

string result = 1400.95.ToString("C");

NumberFormatInfo nfi = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
if (nfi.CurrencyPositivePattern % 2 == 0)
{
    result = nfi.CurrencySymbol +
             result.Substring(nfi.CurrencySymbol.Length).PadLeft(width);
}
else
{
    result = result.PadLeft(width + nfi.CurrencySymbol.Length);
}

// result == "$            1,400.95" (en-US)
//           "£            1,400.95" (en-GB)
//           "           1.400,95 €" (de-DE)
//          "           1.400,95 kr" (sv-SE)
//         "              1.401 kr." (is-IS)
//          "kr            1 400,95" (nb-NO)
//         "kr.            1.400,95" (da-DK) (!)
```

Comment: That's alot of code for a relative simple task :-D But Thanks for your effort.

Comment: It's not a lot of code if you consider that there are many, many languages used on this planet and not everyone is happy to work with Danish output. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Sure this isn't as good as the accepted answer, but I had the same problem with right-alignment and my immediate reflex was to:

```
//Output  kr. 150,45
Console.WriteLine("{0,10}",string.Format("{0:c2}",number1));
```